# Loop through attributes in the custom validation method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to loop through attributes which are validated with custom validation method.
I have model `Post` which `has_many :languages` and a model `Language` which `belongs_to :post`. In the `languages` table I have columns - `id, post_id, language`.

Post model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :languages

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :languages, reject_if: :all_blank
  validates_associated :languages
end
```

Language model:

```
class Language < ApplicationRecord

  validate :unique_languages?

  def unique_languages?
    #LOOP ATTRIBUTES
  end
end
```

IIn the `Language` model in the `unique_languages?` I want too loop through  all language attributes of the post.
This is `posts_controller` with strong params and logic for creating a post:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @post = Post.new
    @post.languages.build if @post.languages.empty?
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.languages.build if @post.languages.empty?
    if @post.save
      redirect_to action: 'new'
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, languages_attributes: [:language])
  end
end
```

Comment: What things do you want to be unique

Comment: Hi, I found that there is a bug in Rails about validates_uniqueness_of with scope when you are using nested attributes and I am trying to validate uniqueness of the language column in languages table with scope (in this case :post_id) with custom validation, but for this I need access to all languages .

Answer (score 1):

```
## app/validators/nested_attributes_uniqueness_validator
class NestedAttributesUniquenessValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    raise ArgumentError if options[:parent].blank?

    association = record.class.to_s.pluralize.underscore # :languages
    items =
      record                    # @language
        .send(options[:parent]) # @language.post
        .send(association)      # @language.post.languages
        .select(attribute)      # @language.post.languages.select(:language)

    unless items.distinct.size == items.size
      record.errors.add attribute, :nested_attributes_uniqueness
      # Don't forget to translate `errors.messages.nested_attributes_uniqueness`
    end
  end
end


## app/models/post.rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :languages, inverse_of: :post # :inverse_of is important

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :languages, reject_if: :all_blank
end


## app/models/language.rb
class Language < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post, inverse_of: :languages # :inverse_of is important

  validates :language, nested_attributes_uniqueness: { parent: :post }
end
```

Comment: and restart the server :).

Comment: In your code even if the languages are unique, it will return false in this line `items.uniq(&field).size == items.size`. `items.uniq(&field).size` is always 1. I made it in this way - `    languages = items.map{|v| v[:language]}
    unless languages.uniq.size == items.size`, but I don't know how can be more dynamic.

Comment: and you want to make column `language` unique with scope `post_id`? What is the association between `Post` and `Language`? `1-n` or `n-n`?

Comment: Yes, there is a column `language` in `languages` table and `language` column  must be unique with scope `post_id`. The relation is one Post to many Languages. Just in your code `items.uniq(&field).size` is always 1 with or without unique languages. I guess it is because it is array of hashes, but I am not sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163507/discussion-between-gdfgdfg-and-phong-phan).

Comment: Now `items.distinct.size` is always 0

Comment: I've just tested my app and It worked well :(. Try to restart the server and tell me why it was always 0. You can put `debugger` inside our `validator` to see what's happening. Did it work the same as the comment?

Comment: A better option in terms of performances is adding `index` to SQL layer.
`add_index :languages, [:language, :post_id], unique: true`

Comment: Yes, adding index is the solution that I found from GitHub, but it raise MySQL error. Still needs Rails validation because of that. I am using `byebug`. In the validation method when all languages are  different or same `items` is `<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>`, both `items.distinct.size, items.size` are 0 and the condition is always `true`. `association` is a `string "languages"`. I found a solution like this: `items = record.send(options[:parent]).send(association)
    languages = items.map{|v| v[attribute]}
    unless languages.uniq.size == items.size`

Comment: The condition in your solution had `items.size` but you said `items.size` was always 0. `select.distinct`(SQL) and `map.uniq`(Ruby) are the same goal, but we used `select.distinct` for better performance

Comment: In my code `items = record.send(options[:parent]).send(association)` in your code `    items = record.send(options[:parent]).send(association).select(attribute)`. This is always 0. I have 1 mistake in the comment above, it must be `unless languages.uniq.size == languages.size` , where `languages = items.map{|v| v[attribute]}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163507/discussion-between-gdfgdfg-and-phong-phan)

Answer (score 0):

You can access a object attributes by:

```
class Language < ApplicationRecord

   validate :unique_languages?

   def unique_languages?
     self.attributes.each do |attr, value|
       #your code
     end
   end
end
```

your object.attributes return a hash where the keys are the attributes names, and the value is the value for that attribute. Don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but this may helps. Good luck!

Comment: `self.attributes` returns only a hash like this `{"id"=>nil, "post_id"=>nil, "language"=>"English1"} `, but it must be an array of hashes like this. For the example, if user add 2 languages it will be `[{"id"=>nil, "post_id"=>nil, "language"=>"Language1"}, {"id"=>nil, "post_id"=>nil, "language"=>"Language2"}]`